# How to use to_json in a loop to create json for each key, value pair where key is to json file name and value is dataframe to be converted into json?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have dictionary with keys are strings,and values are dataframes. I want make a json for each df in dictionary with json file name being the corresponding key string of df.

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

df2020=pd.read_csv('areca2020.csv')

df2019=pd.read_csv('areca2019.csv')

df2018=pd.read_csv('areca2018.csv')

df2017=pd.read_csv('areca2017.csv')

df2016=pd.read_csv('areca2016.csv')

df2015=pd.read_csv('areca2015.csv')





mergelist=[df2015,df2016,df2017,df2018,df2019,df2020]

mergeddf=pd.concat(mergelist,sort=False,ignore_index=True)





groupeddf=mergeddf.groupby('market')


group={}
for g1 in groupeddf:
    group['df{0}'.format(g1)]=g1

values=[]

for keys in group:
    values.extend(list(group[keys]))

dfkeys=[x for x in values if type(x) is str]

dfvalues=[x for x in values if type(x) is not str]

dfdict=dict(zip(dfkeys,dfvalues))

dffill={k:v for (k,v) in dfdict.items() if v.shape[0]>500}





for k,v in dffill.items():
    v.to_json('areca{k}.json'.format(k))
```

But was met with error:

> v.to_json('areca{k}.json'.format(k))
>
> KeyError: 'k'

Is there a way to achieve the end goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I just needed to remove the 'k'

```
 for k,v in dffill.items():
    v.to_json('areca{}.json'.format(k))
```

And I got json files in my working directory.